# Not able to bind IsEanbled property of a button to a textBox.Text.Length

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I am trying to bind IsEnabled property of a button to a TextBox.Text.Length but somewhere I am failing to so.
Idea is to Enable/Disable a button only if a TextBox contains some Text or not.

Pasting the sample code below, please help me out.
Regards,

Dheeraj

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BindButtonToTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isTextEntered;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool EnableOKButton
        {
            get { return isTextEntered; }
            set
            {
                if (textBoxOne.Text.Length != 0)
                    isTextEntered = true;
                else
                    isTextEntered = false;

                OnTextEneterd("EnableOKButton");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnTextEneterd(string propValue)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propValue));
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //button.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use converter that checks whether the text is null /not null & return a boolean on Button's IsEnabled property(bind to TextBox's Text)

Comment: @Nikita: Can show me some example of it OR some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

this a pseudo code & need to be modified:

converter:

```
public class textToEnabledConverter:IValueConverter
{
   ...convert(...)
   {
     if(String.IsnullOrEmpty(value))
    {
      return false;
    }
     return true;
  }
   ...convertBack(...)
  {
    //do not modify
  }
}
```

xaml (define ns as the namespace where the converter class exists):

```
<Windows.Resources>
<ns:textToEnabledConverter x:key=con/>
</Windows.Resources>
<TextBox x:name="txtData"/>
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtData,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource con}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties in the view model as well.

```
private string _inputString;
public string InputString {
  get { return _inputString; }
  set {
    _inputString = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("InputString");
    RaisePropertyChanged("IsValidLength");
  }
}
public bool IsValidLength {
  get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputString) || InputString.Length <= MAX_LENGTH; }
}
```

And make binding.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsValidLength}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Button>
```

(Please note that the code above is not intensively tested.)